# HTML <object> Tag to embed another webpage

Tags: html

while I was revising the HTML in general this sentence in w3 schools appears in front of me 
[from w3schools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHrKx.png)

and I tried to apply it in different ways but it was no success :(
can you help me 
thanks

Comment: Share some code, show us what you've already tried.

Comment: Why would you use that over an `<iframe>`? Also, why would you use w3schools?

Comment: I solved it guys thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I solved it guys finally :) and its so simple

> < object data="https://stackoverflow.com"> < /object>

and it's done!!
of course you can add the width